# Kubeadm Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for kube-system

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, flannel

No matter what I do it seems I cannot get rid of this problem.  I have installed Kubernetes using kubeadm many times quite successfully however adding a v1.16.0 node is giving me a heck of a headache.

O/S: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Kubernetes version: v1.16.0
Kubeadm version: Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:34:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"

A query of the cluster shows:

```
    NAME                  STATUS                     ROLES    AGE     VERSION
kube-apiserver-1      Ready                      master   110d    v1.15.0
kube-apiserver-2      Ready                      master   110d    v1.15.0
kube-apiserver-3      Ready                      master   110d    v1.15.0
kube-node-1           Ready                      <none>   110d    v1.15.0
kube-node-2           Ready                      <none>   110d    v1.15.0
kube-node-3           Ready                      <none>   110d    v1.15.0
kube-node-4           Ready                      <none>   110d    v1.16.0
kube-node-5           Ready,SchedulingDisabled   <none>   3m28s   v1.16.0
kube-node-databases   Ready                      <none>   110d    v1.15.0
```

I have temporarily disabled scheduling to the node until I can fix this problem.  A query of the pod status in the kube-system namespace shows the problem:

$ kubectl -n kube-system get pods

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-fb8b8dccf-55zjs                    1/1     Running            128        21d
coredns-fb8b8dccf-kzrpc                    1/1     Running            144        21d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-29xp2                1/1     Running            11         110d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-hp7nq                1/1     Running            14         110d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-hvdpf                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          8m28s
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-jhhlk                1/1     Running            11         110d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-k6dzc                1/1     Running            2          110d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-lccxl                1/1     Running            21         110d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-nnn7g                1/1     Running            14         110d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-shss5                1/1     Running            7          110d
```

kubectl -n kube-system logs -f kube-flannel-ds-amd64-hvdpf

```
I1002 01:13:22.136379       1 main.go:514] Determining IP address of default interface
I1002 01:13:22.136823       1 main.go:527] Using interface with name ens3 and address 192.168.5.46
I1002 01:13:22.136849       1 main.go:544] Defaulting external address to interface address (192.168.5.46)
E1002 01:13:52.231471       1 main.go:241] Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-hvdpf': Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-hvdpf: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

Although I had a few hits on iptables issues and kernel routing I don't understand why previous versions have installed without a hitch but this version is giving me such a problem.

I have installed this node and destroyed it quite a few times yet the result is always the same.

Anyone else having this issue or has a solution?

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if this has anything to do with it:  
```I1002 20:32:20.863074       1 event.go:258] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"DaemonSet", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"kube-proxy", UID:"119c388d-8d81-11e9-ac35-fa163e6990cb", APIVersion:"apps/v1", ResourceVersion:"21077733", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedCreate' Error creating: Pod "kube-proxy-kx7df" is invalid: spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Forbidden: disallowed by cluster policy```

Answer (score 8):

This occurs when its not able to lookup the host add the below after name: POD_NAMESPACE

```
- name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
          value: "10.220.64.186" #ip address of the host where kube-apiservice is running
        - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT
          value: "6443"
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/) about version skew policy:

> #### kubelet
>
> `kubelet` must not be newer than `kube-apiserver`, and may be up to two minor versions older.
>
> Example:
>
> - `kube-apiserver` is at **1.13**
> - `kubelet` is supported at **1.13**, **1.12**, and **1.11**

That means that worker nodes with version `v1.16.0` is not supported on master node with version `v1.15.0`.

**To fix this issue I recommend reinstalling node with version `v1.15.0` to match the rest of the cluster.**

Optionally You can upgrade whole cluster to `v1.16.1` however there are some problems with it running flannel as network plugin at the moment. Please review [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/) from documentation before proceeding.

Comment: Using your recommendation I decided to upgrade to 1.16.1 and flannel does indeed have a problem but the cluster is now fully operational and has been for at least a week.  There are some errors in the flannel pods that I need to address but these will go away once I change to using Calico as the CNI.